# RecyclerView items does not expand horizontally in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I've a view hierarchy like this. Reason why I'm putting all my `ConstraintLayout` inside of `NestedScrollView` is because I want to be able to scroll `RecyclerView` with `Button` widget together.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  />
        <Button />
        <TextView />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Everything is fine till the moment I try to add childrens to my `RecyclerView`. **It seems that they do not expand fully horizontally**. I can see that my `RecyclerView` is full width (setting background color to it), but children layout does not. I did try variations - ConstraintLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout. All the same.

My child layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView         
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_above"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The weird part is that constraints should be set properly (I can see that in Design mode, items expand correctly). What could cause this?

Comment: Did you set TextViews' layout_width to 0 to enforce the constraints?

Comment: @plaskoff Yes, I did for both `TextViews`

Comment: Which version of `ConstraintLayout` are you using? How to you add the children to the `RecyclerView`? (code)

Answer (score 2):

How were you inflating your child layout? My guess is you did something like this: `LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.my_row, null);`

The error above is in passing `null` as the parent. (Android Studio's linter flags this as a warning as well.) Rather than that, when implementing `onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`, inflate your new child like this:

```
View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
```

where `parent` is the param passed in, so the inflater knows how to deal with the layout parameters at the root of your XML layout.